# Tensorflow frozen inference graph from .meta .info .data and combining frozen inference graphs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow, and currently struggling with some issues :

1. How to get frozen inference graph from .meta .data .info without pipeline config

   I wanted to check pre trained models of traffic sign detection in real time. Model contains 3 files - .meta .data .info, but i cant find information, how to convert them into frozen inference graph without pipeline config. Everything i find is either outdated or needs pipeline config.

   Also, i tried to train model myself, but i think that problem is .ppa files (GTSDB dataset), because with .png or .jpg everything worked just fine.
2. How to combine two or more frozen inference graphs

   I have successfully trained model on my own dataset (detect some specific object), but i want that model to work with some pre trained models like faster rcnn inception or ssd mobilenet. I understand that i have to load both models, but i have no idea how to make them work at the same time and is it even possible?

**UPDATE**

I'm halfway there on first problem - now i have frozen_model.pb, problem was in output node names, i got confused and didn't know what to put there, so after hours of "investigating", got working code:

```
import os, argparse

import tensorflow as tf

# The original freeze_graph function
# from tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph import freeze_graph

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def freeze_graph(model_dir):
    """Extract the sub graph defined by the output nodes and convert
    all its variables into constant
    Args:
        model_dir: the root folder containing the checkpoint state file
        output_node_names: a string, containing all the output node's names,
                            comma separated
    """
    if not tf.gfile.Exists(model_dir):
        raise AssertionError(
            "Export directory doesn't exists. Please specify an export "
            "directory: %s" % model_dir)

    # if not output_node_names:
    #     print("You need to supply the name of a node to --output_node_names.")
    #     return -1

    # We retrieve our checkpoint fullpath
    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_dir)
    input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path

    # We precise the file fullname of our freezed graph
    absolute_model_dir = "/".join(input_checkpoint.split('/')[:-1])
    output_graph = absolute_model_dir + "/frozen_model.pb"
    # We clear devices to allow TensorFlow to control on which device it will load operations
    clear_devices = True

    # We start a session using a temporary fresh Graph
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:

        # We import the meta graph in the current default Graph
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=clear_devices)

        # We restore the weights
        saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)

        # We use a built-in TF helper to export variables to constants
        output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
            tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes
            [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node] # The output node names are used to select the usefull nodes
        )

        # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
        print("%d ops in the final graph." % len(output_graph_def.node))

    return output_graph_def

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--model_dir", type=str, default="", help="Model folder to export")
    # parser.add_argument("--output_node_names", type=str, default="", help="The name of the output nodes, comma separated.")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    freeze_graph(args.model_dir)
```

I had to change few lines - remove --output_node_names and change output_node_names in output_graph_def to `[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]`
Now i got new problems - I can't convert .pb to .pbtxt, and error is :

```
ValueError: Input 0 of node prefix/Variable/Assign was passed float from prefix/Variable:0 incompatible with expected float_ref.
```

And once again, information on this problem is outdated - everything i found is at least year old. I'm starting to think that fix for frozen_graph is not correct, and that is the reason why i'm having new error.

I would really appreciate some advice on this matter.

Comment: This link might help you https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18080

Comment: Also this URL https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-saving-restoring-and-mixing-multiple-models-c4c94d5d7125

Answer (score 0):

if you write

```
[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

in your convert_variables_to_constants function, you define every node the graph has as an output node, which of course will not work. (This is probably the reason for your ValueError)

You need to find the name of the real output node, the best way for this is often to look at the trained model in tensorboard and analyze the graph there, or you print out every node of your graph. Often the last node that is printed out is your output node (ignore everything that has 'gradients' in the name or 'Adam' if you have used that as an optimizer)

An easy way to do this (insert it after you restore the session):

```
gd = sess.graph.as_graph_def()
for node in gd.node:
    print(node.name)
```