# Convert ckpt files to frozen inference graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I have checkpoint files  *.data, *.index and *.meta. I have to convert these checkpoint files into a frozen inference graph. I have seen [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50603972/tensorflow-frozen-inference-graph-from-meta-info-data-and-combining-frozen-in). You can download my checkpoint files from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13VxyxkIpoY1PJqtp--wN3YahzX5mUN3l/view?usp=sharing)

Heres what I did:

**Step 1:**
Display internal layers of the graph using following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./VGGnet_fast_rcnn_iter_50000.meta', clear_devices=True)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, "./VGGnet_fast_rcnn_iter_50000")

for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
    print(n.name)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./log/', sess.graph)
```

Here's the output :

[checkpoints.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J4Lafzau8NL5CcTzRTFr18vaTTcJV56s/view?usp=sharing)

Using checkpoints.txt and *.data, *.index and *.meta I want to create frozen inference graph

My main challange is to find output node names from checkpoints.txt file. If you see this file there are list of names without clear seperation on which exactly is the output

Once I find the output node names. Creating a frozen graph is a easy ride. **How do I find which is my output from list of names in checkpoints.txt file ?**

Comment: OUTPUT NODE NAME = Reshape_2. I came to this conclusion by literally trial and error. There has to be some logic to identify outputnode names from this messy checkpoints.txt file

Comment: ** output_node_names = 'Reshape_2,rpn_bbox_pred/Reshape_1'